# Cannot find associated value in a hashmap from a passed in key

Tags: java

I am working with some existing code in my Eclipse project.  In the method below called `cardTypeForPbfValue()`, I cannot find the key in the `HashMap` even though I can see it while debugging my the code.  The `pbfValueMap` is populated as follows:

```
[1=ATM, 2=DEBIT, 3=CREDIT, 4=PAYROLL]
```

I'm not sure why I cannot get the associated value of `CREDIT` when I'm passing in a value of 3 in the `cardTypeForPbfValue()` below. I am actually getting a value of `NULL`.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
public static enum CardType {
    CREDIT(3),
    ATM(1),
    DEBIT(2),
    PAYROLL(4);
    CardType(int pbfValue) {
        this.pbfValue = (short) pbfValue;
    }

    public static HashMap<Short, CardType>  pbfValueMap = new HashMap<Short, CardType>();
    static {
        for (CardType cardType : CardType.values()) {
            short value = cardType.pbfValue;
            pbfValueMap.put(cardType.pbfValue, cardType);
        }
    }

    public static CardType **cardTypeForPbfValue**(int pbfValue) {
        CardType returnValue = pbfValueMap.get(pbfValue);
        if (returnValue == null) {
            returnValue = DEBIT;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public short    pbfValue;
}
```

Comment: it is int, cast it to short first.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking up an `Integer`, but you put a `Short` into the map. Try this:

```
public static CardType cardTypeForPbfValue(int pbfValue) {
    Short shortPbfValue = (short) pdbValue;
    CardType returnValue = pbfValueMap.get(shortPbfValue);
    ...
}
```

Better yet, stop using `int` everywhere (or stop using `short` for the map) - just be consistent in the type that you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Trying to fix existing code and I've been looking at this way too long.

Answer (score 1):

What I guess is that you are using `Short` as the key type whereas, you are looking for the value in `HashMap` with `Integer` key.That's why you are not getting the associated value for the entered key. To solve this your `cardTypeForPbfValue` method should be like this:

```
public static CardType cardTypeForPbfValue(short pbfValue)
```

And wherever, you call the method `cardTypeForPbfValue` pass the argument of type `short` to it. For example:

```
short s = 1;
CardType cType = cardTypeForPbfValue(s);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate the quick reply.  Looking at this way too long.